# DayPilot - returning a new View on EventClick

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, daypilot

I am currently attempting to implement DayPilot Lite MVC on my project. I've set up my events and they are clickable(tested with a Debug statement). However what i am looking to do is process the click and load a new View, using a ViewModel built from the id of the event I clicked.

```
public ActionResult Booking()
    {
        ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        int id = Dpc.eventID;

        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Lesson lesson = db.Lessons.Find(id);
        if (lesson == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(lesson);
    }

    class Dpc : DayPilotCalendar
    {
        public int eventID;
        protected override void OnInit(InitArgs e)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
            Events = from ev in db.Lessons select ev;

            DataIdField = "ClassID";
            DataTextField = "ClassLevel";
            DataStartField = "ClassStartDate";
            DataEndField = "ClassEndDate";

            Update();
        }

        protected override void OnEventClick(EventClickArgs e)
        {
            //Test to check the method was firing
            Debug.WriteLine("Hey I clicked you");
            //Parse the event ID for processing
            eventID = int.Parse(e.Id);
            //Redirect to the booking page
            Redirect("Schedule/Booking");
        }
    }
```

When I tried to code the Booking method, it resulted in telling me that Dpc.eventID needs an object reference. I have tried making the class and the variable public, but the error persists. I can't make the eventClick public as then i can't override the original. I'm using Redirect because if i try any other link it fails for the same reason. I'm guessing it's because it's a non-inherited subclass, but should i not still be able to access its member attributes if they have a public scope?